# I cannot pinpoint why I am getting ***Exception: Stack overflow

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am writing functions that call other functions. Everything was working fine until I got to comment --A6 AGP(t). When I try running agp1 it throws ***Exception: stack overflow.

I have tried adding and removing parenthesis so that no function is being called over and over, but still no luck.

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

p = 1.50
dt= 0.050
at = 0.075
wMax = 20.00
da1 = 300.0
dcasa = 0.05
dSort = 1.50
dKafv = 0.50
aa1 = 250.0
acasa = 0.05
aKafv = 0.25
aSort = 1.00
v = 1200.0
l = 47490.0


--A1 AGL(t)
agl :: Float -> Float
agl a = a + 5

--A6 AGP(t)
agp :: Float -> Float
agp x = (agp (x-1) - ((at - agp (x-1)) / at)) * (atl (x-1) - at)

agp1 =  agp 2.0

--A7 ATL(t)
atl :: Float -> Float
atl x = (agl x - agl (x+1)) / agl (x)

--A10 DCAS(t)
dcas :: Float -> Float
dcas x = (l/v)*da1*((1.0-dcasa)**(dSort*(x - 1)))*dKafv*(((1 - ((1- 
         dcasa)**(dSort+1))) / dcasa) - 1)


--A11 ACAS(t)
acas :: Float -> Float
acas x = (l/v)*aa1*((1.0-acasa)**(aSort*(x - 1)))*aKafv*(((1 - ((1- 
          acasa)**(aSort+1))) / acasa) - 1)

--A12 Da(t)
da :: Float -> Float
da x = da1 * ((1.0 - dcasa) ** (dSort * (x - 1)))


--A13 Aa(t)
aa :: Float -> Float
aa x = aa1 * ((1.0 - acasa) ** (x - 1))
```

Comment: `agp` is a recursive function that always makes a recursive call - it has no "base case" where it stops, so it will never stop evaluating. (Note that the "stack overflow" in Haskell isn't due to it filling up with function calls, as it would be in other languages - it's due to "thunks", that is unevaluated expressions. But the root cause is the same here, you've got infinite recursion.)

Comment: `agp x = forever (consume stack space)`  Yeah, that's bad.

Comment: Note that the code you actually show doesn't cause the problem, because nothing forces the value of `agp1`. Trying to *print* its value would force it, leading to infinite recursion. (I'm assuming you've left out some code, given the gap between A1 and A6 and the fact that there are several undefined functions, e.g. `agl`.)

Comment: Yes @chepner I meant, when try printing agp1 I get the exception.

Comment: @RobinZigmond If I make a base case of : agp 0.0 = 0.0 I still get the infinite recursion. Am I going about the base case wrong?

Comment: @AprilWilliams Have you checked what the value of `x` is? And is this equation supposed to be recursive?

Comment: @AprilWilliams The base case might not be reached if, say, one starts with `agp 100.5` since we move from `0.5` to `-0.5`. Also, rounding errors might cause an issue since `0.000000001` is not considered `0.0`, so the base case is not met. You could try to define `agp x | x <= 0.001 = 0` so that values that are close enough to 0 and negative values act as a base case. Or you could use an `Int` as an argument (and then convert it to float inside the function, if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You need some base case where `agp` doesn't call itself so the computation ends.
My gues is your function need to be like this:

```
--A6 AGP(t)
agp :: Float -> Float
agp x
    | agp' > 0 = agp'
    | otherwise = 0
    where agp' = (agp (x-1) - ((at - agp (x-1)) / at)) * (atl (x-1) - at)
```